# PowerGui - How do I specify that I only want the first 100 characters of the body?

Tags: powershell, powergui

How do I specify that I only want the first 100 characters of the body?  Right now, I get the message "Warning: column "Body" does not fit into the display and was removed."

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
#connect to outlook
$GetOutlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application"; 
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder(‘olFolderInbox’)
$olxEmailFolder.Name
$olxEmailItem = $olxemailFolder.items

#show unread emails in inbox
$olxEmailItem | select SentOn, SenderName, Subject, Body | Format-Table -auto

#go through each subfolder and get name
$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders
ForEach($Folder in $SubFolders)
{
   $Folder.Name
   $SubfolderItem = $Folder.Items
   $EmailCount = 1
#create status bar for each subfolder
   ForEach($Email in $SubfolderItem)
   {
     Do
     {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Checking folder" -status $Folder.Name -PercentComplete ($EmailCount/$Folder.Items.Count*100)
        $EmailCount++
     }
#show unread emails from subfolders
     While($EmailCount -le $Folders.Item.Count)
   $Email | select SentOn, SenderName, Subject, Body | Format-Table -Auto
   }
}
#connect to tasks
$olxTasksFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder(‘olFolderTasks’)
$olxTaskItems = $olxTasksFolder.items
$TaskCount = 1
#create task array
$TaskList = @()
ForEach($TaskItem in $olxTaskItems)
{
#create status bar for tasks
   Do
   {
     Write-Progress -Activity "Checking" -status "Tasks" -PercentComplete ($Taskcount/

$olxTasksFolder.Items.count*100)
     $TaskCount++
   }
#add each incomplete tash to array
   While($TaskCount -le $olxTaskFolder.Items.Count)
   If($TaskItem.Complete -eq $False)
   {
   $TaskList+=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
   Subject=$TaskItem.Subject
   DateCreated=$TaskItem.CreationTime
   Percent=$TaskItem.PercentComplete
   Due=$TaskItem.DueDate
   }}
}
#show task array to screen
$TaskList | Sort DueDate -descending | Format-Table -Auto
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

For example, replace:

```
select Body
```

With:

```
select @{n='BodySubstring';e={$_.Body.Substring(0,100)}}
```